# Change my data result from my table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Quarters    Status1 Status2 Status3 Status4
Quarter1    NULL    1        NULL   1
Quarter3    NULL    NULL     NULL   1
Quarter4    NULL    NULL     NULL   2
Quater1      0       0        0     0
Quater2      0       0        0     0
Quater3      0       0        0     0
Quater4      0       0        0     0
```

when i execute my Query give me the result like this

Comment: `REVERSE` is something completely different, it **reverses** the characters of a string: `REVERSE('Mystring') = 'gnirtsyM'`. What you are after here is pivoting, both an unpivot and then pivot. There are 100's of examples of bothnon SO; what have you tried and why didn't they work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a PIVOT which is a bit more specific.

```
Select *
 From  (
         Select Quarters = concat('Quarter',DATEPART(QUARTER,EndDate))
               ,Item     = [Name]
               ,Value    = count(*)
          From  TS
          Group By DATEPART(QUARTER,EndDate),[Name]
        Union All
        Select Quarters
              ,Item
              ,Value = 0
         From ( values ('Quarter1')
                      ,('Quarter2')
                      ,('Quarter3')
                      ,('Quarter4')
              ) A(Quarters)
         Cross Join ( Select distinct Item=[Name] from TS)  B
       ) src
 Pivot ( sum(Value) for Item in ([Status1],[Status2],[Status3],[Status4],[Status5],[Status6]) ) pvt
```

Comment: Can i change Null value To 0 i 'am using this funct ( iSnULL(count(*),0)) but not working!!!

Comment: @marcodebala rather than Select * ...   you can specify the columns.   One moment to edit the answer

Comment: thank you sir but i mean in table show me all 4 quarter and when the status is null show the quuarter with status(the status value 0) .

Comment: @marcodebala Not clear.  Perhaps if you edit your question and provide a small  data sample and desired results.

Comment: @marcodebala Updated the answer.  Notice I added a UNION ALL.  this will create and zero intersection of data and also eliminates the need for ISNULL()

Comment: thank you a lot but the select give me data like this  i update the Question

Comment: @marcodebala There is a typo  I have Quater1/4  Shourl be Quarter1/4.    Correcting

Comment: @marcodebala Impossible to tell what your original  data looked like now.   Edit your question and put the sample data and desired results back in

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PIVOT and UNPIVOT relational operators to change a table-valued expression into another table.

```
SELECT <<Columns>> 
FROM <<Tables>> 
PIVOT
 (
   AggregateFunction(<<ColumnToBeAggregated>>)
   FOR PivotColumn IN (<<PivotColumnValues>>)
 ) AS <<Alias>>
```

Source: [SQL Server Docs PIVOT/& UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)